# UEFI mixup with previous windows 10 disk on Lenovo

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, uefi, grub2

### Intro

I am asking the same question as I asked on askUbuntu (but did not get feedback).
References: https://askubuntu.com/questions/714839/uefi-mixup-with-previous-windows-10-disk-on-lenovo

### Question

I have a lenovo laptop that originally had one disk with windows 10 using UEFI. I decided to replace the HDD with an SSD. Additionally, I replaced my DVD-ROM with an adaptor and put my older windows 10 HDD in there.

I installed linux on the SSD (with the second drive removed) and everything worked fine (UEFI mode). However, when I slide in the second disk, the computer goes into an infinite reboot loop as if it is trying to load from the 2nd drive.

I am only able to boot successfully by pressing the novo button and manually selecting a disk.

However, if I remove the second drive (holding windows 10), everyting works fine. I have tried changing the priority in the bios for UEFI boot order but it makes no difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I also tried the utility boot-repair but no luck. Booting from the novo button all the time doesn't seem to be a solution as it's a good way to break that button.
Update

Here is the report from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14298897/

Is there a chance I could delete the EFI partition from the second disk and solve my problem in that manner?

### Summary

The second disk with the UEFI windows 10 is causing the computer to be unbootable even if the first disk (SSD) has a proper UEFI system installed.

Currently, I ended up switching to legacy on the SSD and now my OS on there works fine but I still need to use the Novo Boot Loader (button) to load windows 10 from the second drive.

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed delete EFI System partition on Windows disk (backup partition first!) and don't resize partitions on Windows disk after that! (So you could easily restore ESP in same place on disk).

But first of all you can try adding a boot entry in NVRAM and create BCD on SSD
using bcdboot.exe - it will place also other Windows boot related files on ESP!

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s S:
```

where S: is mapped to EFI System(ESP) on SSD and C: is Windows partition.

You can map ESP using mountvol.exe or diskpart.exe.

Always be sure to boot any OS or recovery DVD/USB using UEFI boot(don't enable CSM).

You could use also [Dual-boot Repair tool](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) (option Automatic Repair) for displaying current system partition(mapped automatically to drive Z:) and type of current firmware boot used - UEFI or MBR.

I would place Windows on SSD and Linux on HDD later. Why? We don't know what the next big update of Windows will bring and Windows is more demanding on resources in wanting to be the main (and only) OS installed (also refuses to chain load foreign OSs like Linux on UEFI). For exchanging contents of disks you could use an external USB backup disk and Macrium Reflect for example. After exchange of disk contents fix of Linux and Windows boot loaders/managers would be necessary.